# I need help to make FB.api() call in Synchronous Mode

Tags: javascript, facebook

I am facing a problem with runing FB.api in a for loop.

```
for(var i = 0; i < commentObjectLength; i++){
    var fbFeedID = commentObject.OwnCommentList[i].fbFeedID;
    var OwnCommentID = commentObject.OwnCommentList[i].OwnCommentID;
    var accessToken = commentObject.OwnCommentList[i].accessToken;
    var commentText = commentObject.OwnCommentList[i].commentText;
    alert("Hiii"); //  >>>>>>>1

    FB.api('/' + fbFeedID + '/comments', 'post', {
            message: commentText,
            access_token : accessToken
        }, function (response) {
            if (!response || response.error){
                //alert(response.error.message);
            } else {
                alert("Hello"); //  >>>>>>>2
                alert(response.id); //  >>>>>>>3
            }
        });
}
```

Now to tell in simple way.
I am expecting out in alert like
1-> Hiii
2-> Hello
3-> some response id
4-> Hiii
5-> Hello
6-> some resonse id

But in reality I am getting out like
1-> Hiii
2-> Hiii
3-> Hiii

continues till loop size
8-> Hello
9-> some response id
10-> Hello
11-> some response id continues

Problem is all time the last date of loop will go to Facebook and comment on feed. Not separately.

So please any one help me solve this issue. I am struggling a lot.
(Hope every one can understand problem, anything extra info needed please ask)

Answer (score 0):

FB.* is event based there are some tricks to make it more synchronous  but it will not work realy. You need to chain your function call.

```
for(var i = 0; i < commentObjectLength; i++){
    var fbFeedID = commentObject.OwnCommentList[i].fbFeedID;
    var OwnCommentID = commentObject.OwnCommentList[i].OwnCommentID;
    var accessToken = commentObject.OwnCommentList[i].accessToken;
    var commentText = commentObject.OwnCommentList[i].commentText;

    FB.api('/' + fbFeedID + '/comments','post',{
            message: commentText,
            access_token : accessToken
        }, function (response) {
            alert("Hiii"); //  >>>>>>>1
            if (!response || response.error){
                //alert(response.error.message);
            } else {
                alert("Hello");//  >>>>>>>2
                alert(response.id); //  >>>>>>>3
            }
        });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to go little further and to study [Closures](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Guide/Closures) It will give you proper solution for this problem.

Closures give you a way to keep all the variable values in its own function call that's why when FB.api will return to your code with response, all the local variables will have the same value when FB.api was called. I am sure this will solve your problem.